# Multiple free texts in one survey question in Redcap

Tags: redcap

I want to create a survey question like: what three questions do you have?
Question1:
Question2:
Question3:
How can I create one includes three free text questions?

Please help me or give me some hints. Thank you!mmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: These are three separate questions. Why not have three separate fields? If you want to get fancy, you can add branching logic to 3 so that it appears only when 2 is nonempty, and the same for 2 based on 1. Or you can embed them into a table to make them all appear together using the {field} syntax in a descriptive text field.